# Are citations in PhD theses indexed by Google Scholar?

Tags: citations, thesis, google-scholar

I've recently seen a few PhD theses that cite work by our lab, but these citations don't seem to be included in Google Scholar despite the fact that the theses themselves are listed as a publication by the authors. Are these citations excluded? If so, why?

Comment: Google needs to be able to access the thesis electronically. If it is openly available as a pdf online this helps a lot.

Comment: The theses I mentioned were indexed by Google Scholar in 2015 and link to a PDF

Comment: In the dark ages, before the internet, the Scitation Index (science citation reference books) only indexed archival journals. I really don't see quite why non-peer-reviewed theses should be included in a citation count any more than random uploads to to the various pre-print sites, just because they can be found by Google...

Comment: @JonCuster Google scholar seems to index everything that can't hide in a tree and vaguely looks like a scientific paper. I've seen slides of talks indexed and also lists of books and paper indexed that are not bibliographies but just a catalog of books and papers…

Comment: @Dirk - well, so much for my using Google Scholar for anything... Sigh.

Comment: Hi, I think that it might be possible that Google Scholar isn't indexing the cited references in those theses because theses tend to be large documents, and Google Scholar declares they don't index files that exceed 5MB. Could you point me to some of these theses? I'd be interested in checking them out (I'm interested in this kind of technical details about Google Scholar).

Comment: I don't see a point in doing this. Yes, there's some kind of "peer-review" for PhD thesis but still at least in chemistry a PhD thesis isn't really seen as a full-value publication.

Comment: I have direct evidence that, at least in some cases, citations in a thesis will be computed, also for large documents. The version of my thesis available online is over 13 MB (https://cora.ucc.ie/handle/10468/1344). In it I obviously cite several papers. The Google Scholar citation records for those papers correctly show the citations appearing in my thesis (at least for those I checked).

Comment: Since the citation in my thesis of a paper I wrote with a coauthor shows up as a citation on my google scholar profile: Yes, at least sometimes such citations get indexed.

Comment: A master's thesis cited a paper of mine. It was indexed and Google Scholar considers it as a paper citing my own paper. The thesis is available as a pdf hosted on a .edu website.

Answer (score 7):

My own PhD thesis has been indexed, but the citations in it haven't, while the citations in other theses published at the same time have been indexed long ago.

I suspect the reason of this is the fancy cover page of my thesis, which doesn't match the document format expected by Google Scholar. For instance, the title should usually be the first line of text in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The citation on my thesis has been indexed. I am not sure if all citations have been indexed, but I can see at least 1 one indexed citation.

Excluding citations could be because of many reasons. A few are:

1. Someone who is citing does not use the link of your thesis/dissertation in their references. I have seen these issues being common not only in dissertations or theses but also in extension materials. For example, if you have an extension bulletin published and cited but the link to the article is not available in the paper, your extension bulletin might not get indexed.
2. Thesis or dissertation not published in Google-indexed sites: Not all thesis are available on websites that publish thesis but can be accessed online from various sources. Citations in this thesis may not be indexed. In that case, I suggest publishing in preprint archive sites. There are several of them available: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_preprint_repositories